# Galois Theory problem (How to find a Galois Group)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm quite new to Galois Theory and I'm having some troubles while solving one of my first exercises.

I've got $f(x) = x^4 - 8$

I've already proved that it's irreductible on the rationals and that its splitting field is $K= \mathbb{Q}[8^{1/4},i]$ (Hope it's correct)

Now, my question is: How do I find?
a) A primitive element of $K/\mathbb{Q}$?

b) How do I find the Galois Group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$?

c) Which is the subextension latice of $K/\mathbb{Q}$?

Thank in advance for the help ^^

Comment: A hint for part b: you know that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=8$, so there are eight automorphisms. An automorphism $\sigma$ is fully determined, if you specify $\sigma(8^{1/4})$ and $\sigma(i)$. How many combinations of possibilities are there? Then you need to just identify the group, and call upon (or review) your database of groups of order 8. Part c) is then just an application of Galois correspondence. I would say part a) is easiest to do after you have done b) and c), but you can probably also start from there.

Comment: In this case there is a geometric picture. You can show that your Galois group is generated by $\sigma : 8^{1/4} \mapsto i \cdot 8^{1/4}, i \mapsto i$ and $\tau : 8^{1/4} \mapsto 8^{1/4}, i \mapsto -i$. If you would "connect the dots" between the zeros of $f$ to make a square, you see that $\sigma$ rotates the square and $\tau$ flips it. You get the symmetry group of the square: $D_8$.

Comment: Wow much thanks. The gometric way of thinking about it has been quite usefull.

For finding a primitive element I've found a usuful theorem to solve itquite in a straight way.

Thanks! ^^